# Number Theory - Factors, HCF and LCM

Tags: math, number-theory

30, 40 and 'n' are such that every number is a factor of the product of other 2 number. If 'n' is a positive
integer , what is the difference between the maximum value of 'n' and the minimum value of 'n'?

Now, since it says that n is a factor of the product of the other 2 numbers, the max value that n can take is 1200 right?

i guess the hcf will give the minimum value of n

Listing the factors of 30 and 40

30 -> 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30

40 -> 1,2,4,5,8,10,20,40

hcf(30,40) -> 10

Therfore, the difference is 1200-10 => 1190..

But the answer that is given is 1188...where am i going wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic here

Comment: *i guess the hcf will give the minimum value of n* <-- This is where you're wrong.

Comment: this does come under number theory and math na???

Comment: how else do i get the minimum value of n?

Comment: You start by asking at the correct website. Surprisingly, there's MATH stachexchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. The greatest common divisor of 30 and 40 is not your smallest `n`.

You are looking for the smallest integer `n > 0` that satisfies `40*n = 0 (mod 30)` and `30*n = 0 (mod 40)`.

For the first equation, the result is `n_1 = 3`. For the second equation, we get `n_2 = 4`. The smallest `n` to satisfy both equations is the least common multiple of `n_1` and `n_2` -- in this case, `n = 12`.

Answer (score 0):

hcf(30,40) -> 12

30=2***3***5

40=2***2*2***5

So, hcf(30,40) -> 3*2*2=12

Comment: While your solution (12) is correct, it is not the highest common factor of 30 and 40. The highest common factor of 30 and 40 is 10. I have no clue why, but you took exactly the prime factors that are *not common* and multiplied them.

Comment: I don't know why you voted down. Are you just needing reputations? I am giving you that! Plz do not vote down just because you don't know why I am right! All information are stated clearly in BOLD, please check carefully! @Carsten

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it is wrong. I explained in my comment what's wrong with it. If you correct your answer, I'll gladly remove that downvote and +1 you.

Comment: The solution is just find the other factors besides the gcd. Isn't it clearly? @Carsten

Comment: It _really_ looks like you're implying that the gcd of 30 and 40 is 12 (at least from my point of view). If one already knows how to get the correct answer, then your answer makes sense. Can't you just add one sentence or something saying that you want to collect the factors that are _not_ part of the gcd?

Comment: Sounds right. @Carsten But I think I have explained it in comments. And the QP has just left. I am saying that IF Bharath Sankar wants to use a programming language to find out the solution, my HINTS are enough. I will NOT see you reply again. Thanks.